# Android onTouchListener, easier way to implement

Tags: java, android

Well, I have 16 buttons. I want to find an easier way to add them to an onTouch listener, I'm new to Android/java so I'm not sure what would work. Here's my code for that right now.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main)
```

.

```
    Button btn_main1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cmd_main1);
    Button btn_main2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cmd_main2);
    Button btn_main3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cmd_main3);
    Button btn_main4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cmd_main4);
    Button btn_main5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cmd_main5);
    Button btn_main6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cmd_main6);
    Button btn_main7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cmd_main7);
    Button btn_main8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cmd_main8);
    Button btn_main9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cmd_main9);
    Button btn_main10 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cmd_main10);
    Button btn_main11 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cmd_main11);
    Button btn_main12 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cmd_main12);
    Button btn_main13 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cmd_main13);
    Button btn_main14 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cmd_main14);
    Button btn_main15 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cmd_main15);
    Button btn_main16 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cmd_main16);


    btn_main1.setOnTouchListener(tListener1);
    btn_main2.setOnTouchListener(tListener1);
    btn_main3.setOnTouchListener(tListener1);
    btn_main4.setOnTouchListener(tListener1);
    btn_main5.setOnTouchListener(tListener1);
    btn_main6.setOnTouchListener(tListener1);
    btn_main7.setOnTouchListener(tListener1);
    btn_main8.setOnTouchListener(tListener1);
    btn_main9.setOnTouchListener(tListener1);
    btn_main10.setOnTouchListener(tListener1);
    btn_main11.setOnTouchListener(tListener1);
    btn_main12.setOnTouchListener(tListener1);
    btn_main13.setOnTouchListener(tListener1);
    btn_main14.setOnTouchListener(tListener1);
    btn_main15.setOnTouchListener(tListener1);
    btn_main16.setOnTouchListener(tListener1);
}
```

Obviously, that's a terrible way to do it. I'm sure there's a way to do some sort of loop, or put the buttons in an array or something. Any help shortening this up is greatly appreciated!

Comment: do you always know at compile time how many buttons there are? If it is the case, then I think I have an elegant solution to reduce verbosity.

Answer (score 1):

Another way could be to add the buttons using code instead of XML.

However, just to clean up that code...

```
int[] buttonIds = new int[]{R.id.cmd_main1, R.id.cmd_main2}; // and so on

for(int buttonId : buttonIds) {
    Button b = (Button)findViewById(buttonId);
    b.setOnTouchListener(tListener1);
}
```

Also, an onClickListener is probably cleaner, depending on what you want the buttons to do. You could then also specify the onClickListener in XML:

```
<Button android:onClick="myClickHandler" />
```

and in the activity, add the corresponding method:

```
class MyActivity extends Activity {
public void myClickHandler(View target) {
    // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: @Henzl0l I think that depends on what you're making. The fact that their names are just indexed by numbers may indicate that. Also, an onClickListener could be preferrable -- will post another answer to highlight code.

Comment: I'm using on touch for a reason, I need the buttons to react the moment they're touched. I'm still new to android, so I'm not sure if there's a better method of doing so.